# Dockerfile: Append/concat to a file from a temporary source

Tags: docker, dockerfile, concatenation, append

How can I append/concat a source file, say "myfile", to another file in the target container, without storing the source file in the final docker image? That is, using the source file only temporarily.

Is there an `APPEND`-like Dockerfile instruction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An [`APPEND`](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/12193)-like instruction for [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/)(s) does not exist.

As of to date, a [`RUN` bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run---mount) is the [most efficient way](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/instructions/#add-or-copy) to temporarily-only use a source file in the build context, i.e. without keeping it in the final image. With this, you only need one `RUN` instruction, thus creating a single cache layer in the Docker image.

For example, to append a temporary source file, do something like:

```dockerfile
RUN --mount=type=bind,source=myfile,target=/tmp/myfile \
    cat /tmp/myfile >> /some/path
```

Note: the `--mount` option requires [BuildKit](https://docs.docker.com/build/buildkit/).

---

The alternative of first `COPY`'ing a temporary file to only removing it later explicitly in a `RUN` instruction of course works, but that would create 2 cache layers in the Docker image:

```dockerfile
COPY myfile /tmp/myfile
RUN cat /tmp/myfile >> /some/path && rm /tmp/myfile
```